# How OpenGL stores commands internally?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

It is said ihat OpenGl driver stores OpenGL commands in some fifo queue 
buffer then it executes it. I am urging to know how it is stored. It is some array containing data records and offsets, enums as command ty;pes or something different? I know that probably this is not standarized so it can be (maybe) done in different ways but I am courious about at least some, one real implementation. How it is/can be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to know, you'd have to go into nVidia or ATI driver code, and that's proprietary. But you can always check the [Mesa GL source code](http://www.mesa3d.org/download.html).